# Can SSL_write() and SSL_read() happen at the same time?

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl, tls1.3

I think in operating system, read() and write() on the same socket could be separated and happen parallel in different threads. However in OpenSSL, the SSL_write() and SSL_read() seems not separately, because they both could issue read and write operations. So, if I am using a TLS based connection with OpenSSL, do I have to create a lock so that SSL_write() and SSL_read() never happens at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/crypto.html) says:

> However it would not be thread safe to call BIO_write() from one thread while calling BIO_read() in another where both functions are passed the same BIO object

`SSL_read` and `SSL_write` use `BIO_read()` and `BIO_write()` internally. So the same holds for `SSL_read` and `SSL_write`: do not use them from different threads without correct locking or synchronization.